Is there a replacement for PRAGMA case_sensitive_like?
SQLite Release 3.44.0 On 2023-11-01 states:

The PRAGMA case_sensitive_like statement is deprecated, as its use when the schema contains LIKE operators can lead to reports of database corruption by PRAGMA integrity_check.

Is there a replacement or do I need to replace things like select X.A from X where A glob ? with select X.A from X where lower(A) glob lower(?)? I'm looking to toggle case sensitivity the way that the pragma directive did.

Do you want case sensitive like or insensitive? The alternate you suggest (lower both sides) will do an insensitive match, which is also the default in SQLite.

@Dogbert : are you sure? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html says "GLOB is case sensitive, unlike LIKE" (and I NEED to use glob). It also says "The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the ASCII range" . Assuming case sensitivity can be dangerous ...

Ah, so you want a case-insensitive GLOB. But then the case_sensitive_like option you mention is unrelated because it makes LIKE case sensitive, it doesn't affect GLOB.

Oooh - that is correct. I'm a goof. However my generic question still stands: what replaces 'case_sensitive_like', since I do have other places where this comes into play?

This question is similar to: Case sensitive and insensitive like in SQLite. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The replacement is to set it on a case by case basis any time you need a compare.

@user1937198 : I'm looking for a replacement for case_sensitive_like. Which doesn't seem to exist :-/ None of the answers in that other question have any value to this question.
